# ¿Cómo puedo escribir en una clase que solo es de escritura?

Tags: java, reflexión

El código relevante en el main es el siguiente:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int mod = getModifiers() & LANGUAGE_MODIFIERS;
if (mod != 0) {
    sb.append(Modifier.toString(mod)).append(" ");
}
sb.append(Field.getTypeName(getReturnType()) + " ");
sb.append(Field.getTypeName(getDeclaringClass()) + ".");
sb.append(getName() + "(");
```

Y me da este error donde quiera que aparezca el `getTypeName`:

> getTypeName(java.lang.Class) is not public in java.lang.reflect.Field;
>   cannot be accessed from outside package

El código (simplificado) donde aparece `getType` es:

```
package java.lang.reflect;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.util.Map;
import sun.reflect.FieldAccessor;
import sun.reflect.generics.factory.GenericsFactory;
import sun.reflect.generics.repository.FieldRepository;

public final class Field extends AccessibleObject implements Member {

    private Class clazz;
    private int slot;
    private String name;
    private Class type;
    private int modifiers;
    private transient String signature;
    private transient FieldRepository genericInfo;
    private byte[] annotations;
    private FieldAccessor fieldAccessor;
    private FieldAccessor overrideFieldAccessor;
    private Field root;
    private Class securityCheckCache;
    private Class securityCheckTargetClassCache;
    private transient Map<Class, Annotation> declaredAnnotations;

    static String getTypeName(Class type) {
            //compiled code
            throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");

        ....
```

Cuando quiero entrar a editar mi código para volver al miembro un atributo público me da el siguiente mensaje:

> Cannot lock read-only file
>   C:/Users/[USER]/.netbeans/6.9/var/cache/index/s14/java/14/gensrc/java/lang/reflect/Field.java

¿Debería buscar la librería en línea y modificar las variables para que lean la nueva versión que yo cree y puedo modificar? ¿O debo recrear toda la clase en mi clase main?

Answer (score 4):

Existe otra forma de obtener el nombre de una clase como un *string*, ya que eso es lo que hace el método `getTypeName` de la clase `java.lang.reflect.Field`: te regresa el nombre de la clase como un *string*.  En otras palabras, necesitas reemplazar líneas de este tipo:

```
sb.append(Field.getTypeName(getReturnType()) + " ");
sb.append(Field.getTypeName(getDeclaringClass()) + ".");
sb.append(Field.getTypeName(params[j]));
```

Por lo siguiente, según sea el caso:

```
sb.append(getReturnType().getName() + " ");
sb.append(getDeclaringClass().getName() + ".");
sb.append(params[j].getClass().getName());
```

Comment: @FabianCervantes si esta respuesta te ha ayudado a resolver tu problema, considera [aceptarla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/227)